# How to install GCC without yum on CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, python, yum, gcc

Is there a real way to install gcc without yum on CentOS 7?

On my system yum doesn't work:

```
yum update
-bash: /usr/bin/yum: /usr/bin/python2.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

And when I want to install `python2.7` it needs GCC that I don't know where it is on my system?

```
which gcc
/usr/bin/which: no gcc in (/root/anaconda2/bin:/root/anaconda3/bin:/root/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/root/anaconda3/bin:/root/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/root/bin)
```

And when I search how to install GCC without yum, most of them need yum! Is there really a way to solve this problem?

Comment: You can fix this with the `rpm` command. Could you update your question with the output of `rpm -V python`, which verifies the python package.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly , CentOS bundled with python i guess , so just check where python ( `which python` )is located and create a link for /usr/bin/python2.7

For Manual install , you have to download the source and install it manually from the tar ball.

This link will help you :

[Ways to install gcc in CentOS 7](https://linuxhostsupport.com/blog/how-to-install-gcc-on-centos-7/)